# Dictionary operation on a list of items

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, hash, iterator

I have a dictionary

```
{ 'a': 1.0,
  'b': 1.1,
  'c': 0.9,
  # ...
  'z': 0.97
}
```

I have a list of items say `['a', 'b', 'c']`. I want to find the average of the values of this list from the dictionary. Of course I can iterate through my list, finding and summing the values, but is there a way in which I can get this without the for loop?

Comment: You could use recursion rather than a loop. Would that suffice?

Answer (score 2):

You *have* to have a loop. You can hide the loop however.

You could use a [`operator.itemgetter()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to do this for you, for example:

```
from operator import itemgetter

average = sum(itemgetter(*list_of_keys)(your_dictionary)) / len(list_of_keys)
```

To be absolutely explicit: the `itemgetter()` now loops over your list of keys and produces a tuple with the corresponding values.

Another 'hidden' loop is the [`map()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map); use either `dict.get()` or `dict.__getitem__()` as the function to map to, and `map()` again does all the looping for you:

```
avegare = sum(map(your_dictionary.__getitem__, list_of_keys)) / len(list_of_keys)
```

The difference between `dict.get` and `dict.__getitem__` here is what excepetion you get when a key is missing; the first will lead to a `TypeError` as you end up trying to sum `None` and a number, the other will give you a `KeyError`.

Otherwise, just use a loop in a generator expression:

```
average = sum(your_dictionary[k] for k in list_of_keys) / len(list_of_keys)
```

Demo:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> d = {'a': 1.0, 'z': 0.97, 'c': 0.9, 'b': 1.1}
>>> selected = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> sum(itemgetter(*selected)(d)) / len(selected)
1.0
>>> sum(map(d.__getitem__, selected)) / len(selected)
1.0
>>> sum(d[k] for k in selected) / len(selected)
1.0
```

Answer (score 2):

If your dict is called `values` and your list is called `items`, there's a very short solution:

```
arithmetic_mean_inexact = sum(values[i] for i in items) / len(items)
```

Note that this doesn't support an empty `items` list, as this will result in a `ZeroDivisionError`.  This is fine, because the average of an empty sequence is not really meaningful.

While this solution shows that computing the average is possible without an *explicit* for loop, it has the problem that summing a big list of floats and dividing it by a big number can result in numerical precision loss.  Fixing that is non-trivial and requires a much longer solution.  Fortunately Python 3.4 (or newer) ships the statistics module for this, so you should use [`statistics.mean()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean) (as was already proposed by another answer).  For example:

```
from statistics import mean
arithmetic_mean = mean([values[i] for i in items])
```

Depending on your concrete problem, other functions in this function might be more appropriate.  You will find more information in the [documentation of the statistics module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#averages-and-measures-of-central-location).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using python3 you could use *statistics.mean:*

```
d = { "a": 1.0,
  "b": 1.1,
  "c": 0.9,

  "z": 0.97
}

lst = ["a", "b", "c"]
from statistics import mean


print(mean(map(d.get, lst)))
```

Or just using sum:

```
print(sum(map(d.get, lst)) / len(lst))
```

That presumes all the items in lst are in the dict, if not you would get an error adding a float and a NoneType.

Comment: Do note that `map()` does a loop too! :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters,  I think no matter what you do there is a loop somewhere ;)

Comment: Exactly, but it is the root of the question.